# Are hyphens allowed in section definitions of INI files?

Tags: parsing, ini

Is it allowed and valid to use hyphens in section definitions within INI files:

```
[my-section]
setting="anything"
```

?

Comment: depends on what you're using to parse it.  There's no official INI specification.  There's some information and informal specs @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

Comment: Ah. If there is no RFC or defined standard, putting it on the parser is the right approach then. Please post as answer so i can accept it.

Comment: The RFC's that you're referencing are likely the IETF RFC's which only apply to Internet standards.  INI files are not an Internet standard and are also not normally used for any form of inter-process or other communication.  Since it is localized in a relatively controlled environment there is less of a need for a formalized spec.

Comment: Interesting info. Thank You for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you're using to parse it. There's no official INI specification. There's some information and informal specs @ en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file.

INI files are not normally used for any form of inter-process or other communication. Since it is localized in a relatively controlled environment there is less of a need for a formalized spec.